# Fetch data from firebase database and store into an array

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm new to the flutter, here I want to know about how to fetch data from firebase realtime database and store that data into an array using flutter. then i want to use that array of data for my rest of the program

Comment: check this link it's very helpful https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data in realtime, use the following code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').document('TESTID1').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return new Text("Loading");
        }
        var userDocument = snapshot.data;
        return new Text(userDocument["name"]);
      }
  );
}
```